# Keep the word frequency and inverse for one type of documents

Tags: r, quanteda, tidytext

Code example to keep the term and inverse frequency:

```
library(dplyr)
library(janeaustenr)
library(tidytext)

book_words <- austen_books() %>%
    unnest_tokens(word, text) %>%
    count(book, word, sort = TRUE)

total_words <- book_words %>% 
    group_by(book) %>% 
    summarize(total = sum(n))

book_words <- left_join(book_words, total_words)

book_words <- book_words %>%
    bind_tf_idf(word, book, n)

book_words %>%
    select(-total) %>%
    arrange(desc(tf_idf))
```

My problem is that this example uses multiple books.

I have different data structure:

```
dataset1 <- data.frame( anumber = c(1,2,3), text = c("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.","It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum", "Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source."))
```

In my case of dataset1 every row is one unique document. I would like to have the same result of term and inverse term frq but I don't know how to make it using my option. How can I start?

Alternative option. From the calcuation of term frequency like this:

```
library(quanteda)
myDfm <- dataset1$text %>%
    corpus() %>%                    
    tokens(remove_punct = TRUE, remove_numbers = TRUE, remove_symbols = TRUE) %>%
    tokens_ngrams(n = 1:2) %>%
    dfm()
```

How is it possible to receive the same result as the one of tidytext, I mean of every word have the score of tf idf, using quanteda package?

What I tried

```
number_of_docs <- nrow(myDfm)
term_in_docs <- colSums(myDfm > 0)
idf <- log2(number_of_docs / term_in_docs)

# Compute TF

tf <- as.vector(myDfm)

# Compute TF-IDF
tf_idf <- tf * idf
names(tf_idf) <- colnames(myDfm)
sort(tf_idf, decreasing = T)[1:5]
```

Is the right option to receive the tf_idf using quanteda for every word frequency?

to receive as output the word, term frequency, tf_idf value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to get a tf-idf per word across your three different documents - in other words, an output data.frame that is unique by word.

The problem is that you cannot do this with tf-idf, because the "idf" part multiplies the term frequency by the log of the inverse document frequency.  When you combine the three documents, then every term occurs in your single combined document, meaning it has a document frequency of 1, equal to the number of documents.  So the tf-idf for every word of a combined document is zero.  I've shown this below.

tf-idf is different for the same words within documents.  That's why the **tidytext** example shows each word by book, not once for the whole corpus.

Here's how to do this in **quanteda** by document:

```r
library("quanteda", warn.conflicts = FALSE)
## Package version: 2.1.1

myDfm <- dataset1 %>%
  corpus(docid_field = "anumber") %>%
  tokens(remove_punct = TRUE, remove_numbers = TRUE, remove_symbols = TRUE) %>%
  tokens_ngrams(n = 1:2) %>%
  dfm()

myDfm %>%
  dfm_tfidf() %>%
  convert(to = "data.frame") %>%
  dplyr::group_by(doc_id) %>%
  tidyr::gather(key = "word", value = "tf_idf", -doc_id) %>%
  tibble::tibble()
## # A tibble: 744 x 3
##    doc_id word   tf_idf
##    <chr>  <chr>   <dbl>
##  1 1      lorem   0    
##  2 2      lorem   0    
##  3 3      lorem   0    
##  4 1      ipsum   0    
##  5 2      ipsum   0    
##  6 3      ipsum   0    
##  7 1      is      0.176
##  8 2      is      0    
##  9 3      is      0.176
## 10 1      simply  0.176
## # … with 734 more rows
```

If you use `dfm_group()` to combine all documents, then you can see that the tf-idf is zero for all words.

```r
myDfm %>%
  dfm_group(groups = rep(1, ndoc(myDfm))) %>%
  dfm_tfidf() %>%
  convert(to = "data.frame") %>%
  dplyr::select(-doc_id) %>%
  tidyr::gather(key = "word", value = "tf_idf") %>%
  tibble::tibble()
## # A tibble: 247 x 2
##    word     tf_idf
##    <chr>     <dbl>
##  1 lorem         0
##  2 ipsum         0
##  3 is            0
##  4 simply        0
##  5 dummy         0
##  6 text          0
##  7 of            0
##  8 the           0
##  9 printing      0
## 10 and           0
## # … with 237 more rows
```

Comment: Many thanks. Actually here what I try to do "The
Column Term Frequency Inverse Document Frequency (TF*IDF) contains values of metrics for an estimation of the importance
of a phrase in a collection of documents. The importance is based on the
ratio between the frequency at which a phrase occurs in a document
and the total number of phrases in the document (TF), along with the
logarithm of the ratio between the total number of documents the
phrase occurs in and the total number of documents present in the
collection (*IDF)."

Comment: No sure if this description makes sense to help understand what I try to do

Comment: It does make sense, but the tf-idf of the phrase exists at the document level, not the corpus level - despite the phrase here "in a collection of documents". You could compute them by document and then aggregate them using `summarize()` if that's what you want to do, but that's not technically tf-idf any more.